# Passing function from DjangoListAPI to a celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

I am having some trouble passing a function to a celery task, and i cant pass its results because it takes much time to load and it times out the api request

```
@celery.task(name='task_name', bind=True)
def celery_task(self, headers, data_function):
    data = data_function()
    # more code
```

```
class DataClass(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         send_excel_as_email.apply_async(args=[headers, self.get_data])

    def get_data(self):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        data = serializer_class(queryset, context=self.get_serializer_context(), many=True).data
        # more code
```

So basically the celery_task is a reusable task that will be used in many other Classes and each class has its own query_set and serializer, thats why i need to find a way to call the `get_data` function inside the celery task itself

i tried using pickl but it throwed errors that it cant serialize the function

Answer (score 0):

You can't serialise functions in celery because internally it uses `json` or `pickle`. So keep the celery_task arguments simple, like `string/list/dict` which are basically serialisable. While writing celery task, assume that they are executed on an entirely different machine and it doesn't have access to your application memory. Brokers are used to store and transport these messages and provide the communication layer. It's better you query the data from the input arguments from their sources.